# Php MySQL query to get max of event id for specific user id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a single table with `event_id`, `eventname`, `date`, `time`, `location`, `user_id`. Each user Id can have multiple event ids. I want to query for just the highest event id where `user id = 30` for example. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT userID, MAX(event_ID) maxID
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY userID
        ) b ON  a.userID = b.userID AND
                a.event_ID = b.maxID
WHERE   a.userID = 30
```

Comment: @raheelshan yes,if the user wants to get all fields, then he should do like this. but if the user wants only the `event_ID`, see bryans's answer.

Comment: JW has it right. I wanted all fields so the other answers don't work. That's why it was not as simple as it appeared. Thank u JW I got it to work with your answer. I'll be accepting it in 2 minutes

Comment: @IanAtkin really? then post an answer that creates simple query which gives correct values on all fields.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    MAX(event_id) as MEvent_id , 
    eventname, 
    date, 
    time, 
    location, 
    user_id 
FROM mytable 
WHERE user_id = 30
```

Comment: this will not give you correct eventname, date, etc.. sometimes.

Comment: [SQLFiddle Demo Link (*gives incorrect values*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7afc8/2)

Comment: Well Great! i really appreciate and now i see how it should be done. I really like to learn MYSQL. Thanks for this explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is incredibly simple.

```
 SELECT MAX(event_id) FROM table WHERE user_id = 30
```